# Negative Look Ahead. Exclude Expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to exclude the following:
Anything starting with a curly brace, followed by the word color.  After color there can be anything.  Once I see the closing curly brace, that entire chunk needs to be eliminated.  See below for the bolded stuff for an example.
This is my expression so far.

```
^(?!.*({color})).*
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
('|Activity|Planned Dates|Actual Dates|Status|\r\n'
'|Dev Cut Off|06/03/22\xa0|06/03/22|Complete|\r\n'
'|AOS Integration|06/10/22|06/10/22|Complete|\r\n'
'|**{color:#de350b}**QA Deploy{color}|{color:#de350b}06/14/22\xa0'
'{color}|{color:#de350b}06/16/22{color}|\r\n'
)
```

Comment: You need to escape `{` since it has special meaning.

Comment: The negative lookahead tests the entire string because of `.*`. So if `{color}` appears anywhere in the input string, it doesn't match.

Comment: Hi Barmar,  I escaped { with \ but it didn't work.  In the example shown above, take a look at the last line.  The correct regex will eliminate {color}.  It will also eliminate {color: #de350b}.  So anything after {color ending with } should be gone.   Thank you for your help.

Comment: The regex doesn't "eliminate" anything. Either the regex matches or it doesn't. It won't match if `{color}` appears anywhere in the string.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  When I am done matching, I should not get any of the following:
{color}
{color:#de350b}
and so on

Comment: What language are you using? Show your code that uses the regex.

Comment: ^(?!.*(\{color\}))
Python.  However, I am doing this using regex101.com.  If you can show me how to make it work over there, that would be great.  I would like to post the complete string, but I am not able to post it.

Comment: That's not code. I want to see something like `re.findall(...)`. Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: What you probably want is `re.split()` to get everything outside the matches.

Comment: Or use `re.sub(r'\{color[^}]*}', '', input)` to remove all the colors.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  I didn't write Python code yet.  I was first practicing doing it in regex101.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is that regex101.com is very limited in the type of results you can get. You can see the matches and you can perform substitutions, but you can't do other things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So use

```py
text = re.sub(r'\{color[^{}]*}', '', text)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fRbPKY/1).

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  color                    'color'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}]*                   zero or more characters different from curly braces
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   }                        '}'
```